# convergence in representation of the Gamma function

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, exponential-function, gamma-function

I was reading the derivation of Euler's reflection formula for Gamma function on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General). It's an easy enough proof that does not require anything sophisticated or technical as other proofs. Then I realized I don't know how to justify the obvious looking representation of the gamma function

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^n t^{x-1} \left(1-\frac{t}{n}\right) ^n dt = \Gamma(x) := \int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt,$$
where $x>0$.
It seems like it's obvious, but stuff like this doesn't hold automatically. Take e.g.
$$f_n(x)= \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n} & 0\leq x\leq n,\\
0 & x>n,
\end{cases} $$
then $f_n \to 0$ (even uniformly), but $\int_0^n f_n = 1$.

If we don't want to just believe it, we need to show that
$$\int_0^n t^{x-1}\left|e^{-t}-\left(1-\frac{t}{n}\right)^n\right| dt \to 0.$$

It would suffice if we had for arbitrary $\varepsilon>0,m>-1$ an estimation
$$\left|e^{-t}-\left(1-\frac{t}{n}\right) ^n\right|\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{nt^m}$$ for $t\in [0,n]$ for large enough $n$'s. But my numerical experiments say this isn't actually true; the approximation of the exponential function is not *that* good.

Seems like something more subtle is needed. But this is where I'm essentially stuck. Any ideas? Quite possibly I'm missing something straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$f_n(t) := t^{x-1} (1-t/n)^n \mathbf{1}_{[0, n]}(t),$$
$$f(t) := t^{x-1} e^{-t} \, dt.$$

One can show that $(1-t/n)^n \le e^{-t}$ for all $n$ by checking that $(1-t/n)^n$ is increasing in $n$ and converges to $e^{-t}$.

So, $0 \le f_n(t) \le f(t)$ for $t \ge 0$. Since $f$ is integrable, we can use the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) to conclude $\int_0^\infty f_n(t) \, dt \to \int_0^\infty f(t) \, dt$ from the pointwise convergence $f_n \to f$.

---

Side note: the conditions for the dominated convergence theorem fail to hold for your example $f_n(t) = \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{1}_{[0,n]}(t)$ because $\sup_{t \ge 0} |f_n(t)|$ decays like $1/t$ which is not integrable.

Comment: omg, thank you! I've completely forgot that dominated convergence is a thing.